# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when use paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I get a wonderful error in a rails project. I have a controller => prdocuts_controller.rb. I use `options_from_collection_for_select` when I want create a new product. Every things are ok when I create a new product, and I can do this, but when I add `file_field` to upload a picture to product, I get below error:

```
NoMethodError in Products#create
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

and when I remove `file.field`, every thing are ok again and new product is save to database.

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  layout "product"
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @categories = Category.all
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @categories = Category.all
    @product = Product.all
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.responsibility = current_user.responsibility
    @product.date_time = Time.now

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:category_id, :name, :code, :date_time, :describe, :picture)
    end
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
  belongs_to :category
end
```

views/products/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <% if @product.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "m-wrap span8", :placeholder => "enter product name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Product Code</label>
        <%= f.text_field :code, :class => "m-wrap span8", :placeholder => "enter product code" %>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" >Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="select2-wrapper">
            <select name="product[category_id]" class="select2_category m-wrap span8">
              <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@categories,:id, :name,@product.category_id) %>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Product Code</label>
        <%= f.text_area :describe, :class => "m-wrap span8", :placeholder => "enter describe" %>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <%= f.file_field :picture %>
      <br/>
      <div class="action">
        <%= f.submit "Save change", :class => "btn green" %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

log  of system:

```
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/MGH~1.119/AppData/Local/Temp/6f87f43a62513173b9edfea7b58ee2d020140504-660-1luu1b5.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/MGH~1.119/AppData/Local/Temp/6f87f43a62513173b9edfea7b58ee2d020140504-660-1luu1b5.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
  Responsibility Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "responsibilities".* FROM "responsibilities" WHERE "responsibilities"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "responsibilities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 17]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
  Rendered products/_form.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/product (13.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 132ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
    27:         <div class="controls">
    28:           <div class="select2-wrapper">
    29:             <select name="product[category_id]" class="select2_category m-wrap span8">
    30:               <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@categories,:id, :name,@product.category_id) %>
    31:             </select>
    32:           </div>
    33:         </div>
```

I use 'paperclip', '~> 3.0' in this project. Any one can help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#map` could be called internally when processing this line from `new.html.erb`:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@categories,:id, :name,@product.category_id) %>
```

I'd guess that it's called on `@categories`.

Here is the problem:
When the user requests the `/new` page, the `new` action is processed and `@categories` is normally initialized.
However, when you `render 'new'` in `create`, Rails will render that template without going through the action in the controller, thus `@categories` will be `nil`.

Try with:

```
def new
  @categories = Category.all
  @product = Product.new
end


def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.responsibility = current_user.responsibility
  @product.date_time = Time.now

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      format.html {
        @categories = Category.all
        render action: 'new'
      }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: By this answer, I can save the product, but paperclip is don't work and I cannot upload picture.

Comment: uhm. It says you're getting a `Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError`. What's the file named?

Comment: Anyway, this question solved the _calling map on nil_ error, which was about Rails controllers and the use of the `render` method. The Paperclip error has a very different scope, and would be tricky to discuss it in the comments. You should create a new question.

Comment: I asked new question. Can you read this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460108/cannot-save-image-by-paperclip-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is `@categories` is nil.  Your product cannot save because of the ImageMagick errors so when you go back to show the view `@categories` is not defined.

You need to include

```
@categories = Category.all
```

in your `create` method in the case where the save fails.  Alternatively consider a `before_filter` in the controller so you can avoid having to repeat code in all your actions.

Why you are getting ImageMagick errors in the first place is another matter, but this is the cause of your `map` error.  Paperclip will throw a `NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError` error where ImageMagick cannot parse the file - normally because it is not a valid image.  You can test this out at the command line.