# cannot save image by paperclip in rails on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use "paperclip", "~> 4.1" (on windows 8) to save picture to my product.
I have below code:

products_controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
  def edit
    @product = Product.all
  end
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)  
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html {
          render action: 'new'
        }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :code,:picture)
    end
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => [ 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg' ]

end
```

but when I want save the picture that I upload, I get below error:

```
1 error prohibited this product from being saved:
Picture has an extension that does not match its contents
```

Log of system:

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 23:23:31 +0430
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XVKgrUjhmB6auJXM5zTrDFrw7GLS0jdUPFelXt4se4Y=", "product"=>{"name"=>"Product 453", "code"=>"324324", "category_id"=>"10", "describe"=>"", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004fdb750 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/MGH~1.119/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140504-5856-p42svx>, @original_filename="pic.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[picture]\"; filename=\"pic.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save change"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Command :: file -b --mime-type "C:/Users/MGH~1.119/AppData/Local/Temp/be0933fb4765581454c720c6cac4755920140504-5856-15ak6qf"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename pic.jpg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
  Responsibility Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "responsibilities".* FROM "responsibilities" WHERE "responsibilities"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "responsibilities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 17]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime-type "C:/Users/MGH~1.119/AppData/Local/Temp/6db10b0624aa4c70237ca9e622c03f4620140504-5856-t1i2gw"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename pic.jpg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Category Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered products/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/product (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 16.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Where is the problem?

And how can I save `pdf` file to `paperclip` and show it in view?

Comment: Could you check your log file - you should have more information about the extension/content mismatch.  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I edit the question and add log of system. I use windows 8.

Comment: Does this happen with _any_ image, or just with this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paperclip introduced spoofing validation at v4.0 to ensure that the contents of the file match the extension.

It uses the `file` command to determine the MIME type of the file which is fine if you use linux or OS X.  Unfortunately Windows doesn't have a `file` command so it comes back with blank - since this doesn't match the expected MIME type of the file according to its extension you get the spoofing error.

This little bit from your log:

`content type discovered from file command: .`

The bit between the colon and the full stop is the output from the `file` command; which on Windows is always going to be blank.

The best workaround I know for Windows is to disable spoofing.  For this you need to put something like this in an initializer:

```
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution proposed by user740584 and it did not resolve the problem for me.  I created a separate file within the intializers folder called "Disable_Spoofing.rb" and placed the suggested code in there.

The way to solve it for me was to downgrade my version of paperclip.  I downgraded from from 4.2.1 to 3.5.3.  I then ran "$ bundle install" and then restarted the rails server and I could then upload images successfully.